# why my program show in bluestack but don't show in my phone

Tags: android, bluestacks

I make program. my program works fully in the bluestacks but in my phone part of my program doesn't work. this part that Has caused a problem the dialog box that show two picture and one note. massage that show in my phone that expresses the reason for the failure is:

> "Unfortunately,(my progarm name's) has stopped."

Part of my program that is work in bluestack and phone then by click one item the problem is create, is:

```
public class Introduction_map_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Context context = this;
    private TextView title_custom;
    private ImageButton imageButton_place;
    private ImageButton imageButton_place_map;
    private TextView textView_place_information;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.layout_custom_title);
        title_custom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_custom);
        title_custom.setText(R.string.introduction_map);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introduction_map);

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_place_information);

            imageButton_place = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton_place);
            imageButton_place_map = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton_place_map);
            textView_place_information = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView_place_information);
        ImageView image_seraglio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_seraglio);
        TextView text_seraglio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_seraglio);
        ImageView image_veranda = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_veranda);
        TextView text_veranda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_veranda);


        image_seraglio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.seraglio_name);
                imageButton_place.setImageResource(R.drawable.seraglio_pic);
                textView_place_information.setText(R.string.seraglio_information);
                imageButton_place_map.setImageResource(R.drawable.seraglio_pic);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        text_seraglio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.seraglio_name);
                imageButton_place.setImageResource(R.drawable.seraglio_pic);
                textView_place_information.setText(R.string.seraglio_information);
                imageButton_place_map.setImageResource(R.drawable.seraglio_pic);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        image_veranda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.veranda_name);
                imageButton_place.setImageResource(R.drawable.seraglio_pic);
                textView_place_information.setText(R.string.veranda_information);
                imageButton_place_map.setImageResource(R.drawable.seraglio_pic);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        text_veranda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.veranda_name);
                imageButton_place.setImageResource(R.drawable.seraglio_pic);
                textView_place_information.setText(R.string.veranda_information);
                imageButton_place_map.setImageResource(R.drawable.seraglio_pic);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

layout this activity:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.rb.musalla.Introduction_map_Activity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_seraglio"
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/seraglio_name"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_seraglio"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/seraglio_name"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:gravity="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="fill"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_veranda"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/veranda_name"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_veranda"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/veranda_name"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and dialog layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:background="@color/custom1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton_place"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:background="@color/custom1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView_place_information"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton_place_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:background="@color/custom1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In addition my phone android version is **upper** bluestacks android version.

that log cat :

03-23 11:19:11.600 580-580/? E/installd: eof
03-23 11:19:11.600 580-580/? E/installd: failed to read size

*thans for Your guide.*

Comment: Post your log cat aswell

Comment: what's your mean? @NizaSiwale

Comment: Your log cat from android studio or any other IDE you are using to program the app

Comment: @NizaSiwale I don't your Purpose but get thing that in log cat android studio.

Comment: You should post your error logs, just after your app crashes on the phone. Your posted logs seems like not related to your error.

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül how send error logs? my program in computer is right but my phone (in the part) gets into trouble.my phone haven't log cat. this log that I sended related to that part in bluestacks.

Comment: Open Android Studio, connect your phone to pc, run your app through AS, create the error case, then look at your logcat output. You will see the errors.

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül what is AS?

Comment: AS is the short version of Android Studio.

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül I put error on log cat but not meaning

Comment: I find problem. this problem that's because phone memory lower computer memory and details set in program (like picture) is large size than memory.